# What do parameters in a () at the tail-end of a function mean? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

In the following code, what does the last line do (the bit within the parenthesis)?

- Is it related to Javascript closures?
- Is it returning a variable?
- Is there a way to write this code without using this short-hand?

Thanks!!

```
(function (window, $, my, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    if (!$) { throw 'jQuery not found.'; }

    my.someNamespace = {

        bla:null,
        blabla:null,

        init: function(){},
        bind: function(){}

    };
} (window, $, window.my = window.my || {}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 5;
(function(y){
   console.log(y); // will print 5
})(x);
```

It’s an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE for short. It executes immediately after it’s created. x is the passed parameter.

Comment: Surely you knew this is a duplicate?

Comment: @Amit probably not, OP was confused with the arguments of IIFE, and not what it is.

Comment: I wasn't even sure what it was called or what to search for (and believe me, I did do a search), so thanks for the quick response!